# MathJax equation numbers do not show using Jekyll on GitHub Pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, equation, mathjax

This is my `mathjax.html`:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js","TeX/AMSmath.js","TeX/AMSsymbols.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex: {
      equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" },
      tagSide: "right"
    },
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    }
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  charset="utf-8"
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

It is being included in `head.html` in the `_includes\` folder

```
{% include mathjax.html %}
```

which is in turn referenced in `default.html` in the `_layouts\` folder

```
{%- include head.html -%}
```

When I then use `\label{eq:xyz}` and `\ref{eq:xyz}` or `\eqref{eq:xyz}` in a Markdown document on the Jekyll website deployed via GitHub Pages,

- equations are not being numbered
- equation references appear as "(???)"

Example:

```
$$ \label{eq:MSE}\tag{1}
\mathrm{MSE}(\hat{\theta}) = \mathrm{Var}(\hat{\theta}) - \mathrm{Bias}(\hat{\theta},\theta)^2
$$
(...)
\eqref{eq:MSE}
```

I have tried virtually any MathJax configuration I could find on the internet, but to no avail. The only way I get it working is to add `\tag{1}`, `\tag{2}`, `\tag{3}`, `...` after the label in each equation and even then, equations using `\begin{split} ... \end{split}` still remain unnumbered. Who can tell me what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `autoNumber: "AMS"` only certain equation environments are numbered automatically.  In particular, math delimited by `$$...$$` are not numbered automatically; you would need to use `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` (or one of the other numbered alignment environments) for that.  So using `\tag{}` is the only way to get an equation number for an equation using `$$...$$`.

If you want double-dollar delimited display equations to be numbered, use `autoNumber: 'all'`.  This will make every displayed equation have a number, not just the AMS numbered environments.

Note also that the `split` environment does not provide equation numbering; it is for use within an outer numbered environment.

---

**Edit**:  It turns out that your issue is the capitalization of the TeX configuration block.  It should be `TeX:` not `tex:` (in version 2, which is what you re using), so your TeX configuration wasn't being found by the TeX input jax, and so wasn't being used.  Here is a working example:

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {
      equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" },
      tagSide: "right"
    },
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    }
  });
  MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX AMSmath Ready", function () {
    MathJax.InputJax.TeX.Stack.Item.AMSarray.Augment({
      clearTag() {
        if (!this.global.notags) {
          this.super(arguments).clearTag.call(this);
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
</script>

<p>
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:square}
\begin{split}
   (x+1)^2 &= (x+1)(x+1)\\
           &= x^2 + 2x + 1
\end{split}
\end{equation}
</p>

<p>
Link to equation \eqref{eq:square}
</p>
```

I've also changed the CDN to not be the decommissioned `cdn.mathjax.org`, and changed the config file to one that just loads TeX (not MathML) and uses the CommonHTML output rather than the older (and slower) HTML-CSS output.  Finally, I removed unneeded pieces of your configuration (the `extensions` and `jax` arrays, since these are already included in the combined configuration file `TeX-AMS_CHTML`.

Comment: I now tried both, (a) ```autonumber: "AMS"``` combined with ```\begin{equation}...\end{equation}``` and (b) ```autonumber: "all"``` combined with ```$$...$$```. **As I expected, both didn't work.** (Likely, these options are part of "virtually any MathJax configuration I could find on the internet", so I've probably tried them before.) Is there anything wrong with the way I call MathJax (maybe leading to configurations being ignored)?

Comment: @JoramSoch, I have edited my answer above to include a working example.  The problem with your configuration was with the capitalization of the TeX configuration block.

Comment: First of all, many thanks for your detailed edit/reply! I now use ```autoNumber: "all"``` together with ```$$...$$``` and it finally works without ```\tag{x}```. I still don't get equation numbers on ```\begin{split}...\end{split}```, even when enclosing it within ```$$...$$``` and if I use ```\begin{align}...\end{align}```, every single line of the equation is numbered (which is not what I want, because I just use one label per group of splitted/aligned equations).

Comment: BTW, I have posted a description of the remaining (smaller) problem here: https://github.com/StatProofBook/StatProofBook.github.io/issues/7.

Comment: @JoramSoch, I have opened a [MathJax issue](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2272) for the problem with a single `split` environment not getting a number when tags are set to `all`.

Comment: A colleague of mine [has posted a solution](https://github.com/StatProofBook/StatProofBook.github.io/issues/7#issuecomment-568090609) which consists in using both, `equation` and `split`, to write `$$ \begin{equation} \label{eq:XYZ} \begin{split} ... \end{split} \end{equation} $$`. In this way, `split`ted equations receive exactly one equation number.

Comment: Erm, it seems that [referencing doesn't work](https://github.com/StatProofBook/StatProofBook.github.io/issues/7#issuecomment-570187339) with this solution. MathJax only displays "(???)".

Comment: @JoramSochm, I've modified my example to include a patch to allow the `split` environment to have a label.  It turns out that it, and other unnumbered environments, were clearing labels when they ended, which is why the reference was being set to `???`.  Add the `MathJax.Hub.Register` call to your configuration to apply the patch.  Alternatively, move the `\label` to just before the `\end{equation}` to get the labels to work without the patch.  I'm adding a fix to the pull request already in place at the MathJax issue linked above.